# TextBlock.Text update ViewModel and CodeBehind WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to set the `Text` property of `TextBlock` both from CodeBehind(xaml.cs) and `ViewModel` Binding.

In default the values are loaded from ViewModel which works fine.

**XAML:**

```
<TextBlock Name="test">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat=" ({0}, {1} of {2})">
            <Binding Path="SeriesId" />
            <Binding Path="SeriesName" />
            <Binding Path="SeriesCalc" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

**XAML.cs**

In a button click event tried the following,

```
test.DataContext = "Not Available";
```

Or

```
test.Text = "Not Available";
```

**ViewModel:**

In another button `Command` i'm trying to assign the value to the `TextBlock`.

```
   SeriesId= GetIds();
   SeriesName= GetNamesWithDE();
   SeriesCalc= CalculateValue();
```

But once the "`Not Available`" is set from code behind, it couldn't be overwritten from `ViewModel`.

Where am i wrong?

Comment: you are not wrong. but if you set the datacontext away from your viewmodel - you can not update the Textblock anymore... btw why in hell you wanna do this??

Comment: In XAML you are setting a binding to your `Text` property. In code behind you are resetting your `Text` property. Hence your binding goes poof.

Answer (score 4):

If you write `test.Text = "Not Available";` then you broke data binding by overwriting them with simple string. If you want to complete, use data binding and change `TextBlock` value from the code behind and you should update binding after that:

```
test.Text = "Not available";
test.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
```

or with [`SetCurrentValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue.aspx) method which sets the value of a dependency property without changing its value source.

```
test.SetCurrentValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, "Not available");
```

Comment: For first result i'm getting `Object reference` error(`null` occurs in `test.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.TextProperty)`) and for the 2nd result the text changes for the second click of the button and remains the same for first click which means it works fine after 2 clicks.

Comment: Since its a MultiBinding it should be something like this, `BindingOperations.GetMultiBinding(test, TextBlock.TextProperty);`. Can you please refine and update using this code?